# Selenium - Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Selenium and all of the sudden for no reason an error is stopping me from running ANY Selenium tests.

This is the error I am getting when I run my Python script:

```
2018-05-14 12:07:52,766 [INFO ]  Getting Selenium setup here.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 308, in <module>
    webcrawler.crawl()
  File "test.py", line 177, in crawl
    self.web_crawl.setup()
  File "/test/src/webcrawlers/utils/webcrawl_lib.py", line 83, in setup
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Now I can usually debug these issues. However, the geckodriver.log is not giving me much to work with:

```
1526299672891   geckodriver     INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1526299672895   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:48641
1526299673899   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.YNIc2l05QiIr"
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($HOME is /home/test which is owned by test.)
```

Environment:

- Geckodriver: 0.20.1
- Selenium: 3.12.0
- Python: 2.7. And I tried using 3 as well
- Firefox: 60.0

I even tried switching out to using Chrome, and the setup would just hang and give a unique error as well.

A side note is that this is on Amazon AWS, and I am not the administrator on the account. Maybe something was changed on that end.

Comment: Are you running as root, as the error implies? Also, when you say "this is on AWS", does that mean the _selenium_ code is running on AWS, or that you're running selenium locally but talking to a server on AWS?

Comment: yes I am running the script as root, yes the code is running on AWS ec2

Comment: It seems like the simple solution is to _not_ run as root. Have you tried that? There's almost never a good reason to run tests as root.

Comment: attempted and I got this error : raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with geckodriver 0.21.1, Selenium 3.12.0, and Python 3.5.2. It worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04 to remove Firefox and (`firefox-dev`) with `sudo apt-get purge firefox, firefox-dev` and then I install Firefox version 50.0 manually with:

```
wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.0/linux-$(uname -m)/en-US/firefox-50.0.tar.bz2
tar -xjf firefox-50.0.tar.bz2
sudo mv firefox /opt/
sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox_old
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

After those steps it also worked with root.

Comment: for geckodriver 0.19 and higher its recommended  Firefox 55.0 (and greater)
Selenium 3.5 (and greater)

Comment: however I took your same idea and rolled it to Firefox 55.0.1 and now it works!